# sql time from value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column with integer values in seconds, ie:

```
Seconds
234555
1123
44567
```

I need to do a select of that column but the return value should be in the form of `1d 13h 23m`

How exactly should I formulate the sql query?

Comment: Another hint, you are allowed to do math in queries.  For example, you can do "select 1 + 1 as two"

Comment: The result should be one cell and it can be a string, not necessarily a date.

Comment: I've updated my response so the result is a string, as you requested.

Comment: And you can't do this server side because...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a good solution but anyways

```
declare @day int
declare @tmpHour int
declare @Hour int
declare @tmpMinute int
declare @Min int

select @day = Seconds_Column/ (24*60*60),@tmpHour = Seconds_Column%(24*60*60)
from yourTable

select @Hour = @tmpHour / (60*60)
select @tmpMinute = @tmpHour%(60*60)
select @Min = @tmpMinute/60

select cast(@day as varchar) + ' day '+ 
       cast(@Hour as varchar) + ' hour ' + 
       cast(@Min as  varchar) + ' min'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select
    CAST(seconds/60/60/24 as VARCHAR) + 'd ' + 
    CAST(seconds/60/60%24 as VARCHAR) + 'h '+ 
    CAST((seconds/60)%60 as VARCHAR) + 'm ' +
    CAST(seconds%60 as VARCHAR) + 's'
from your_table
```

I've updated my response as per your comment

Comment: Funny thing is that my solution has the exact same functionality as the correct answer except without all the variable declarations.

Comment: The second calculation should probably go `seconds/60/60%24`. Other than that, I'd agree, variables seem perfectly superfluous to solving this.

Comment: It could be either one. Anyway, I found a small error in my code, I was missing a `+`. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Sorry, I must have confused you somehow. The first calculation, which went `seconds/60/60/24` at the time of my comment, was correct, you should *not* have changed it to `seconds/60/60%24`. The issue was (and still is) with the second one. The present `seconds/60/60` expression returns the *total* number of whole hours in the `seconds` column. You should take it by modulo 24 to get the number of hours remaining after removing the whole days, i.e. it should be `seconds/60/60%24`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the values come from a column named INTERVAL, you can use the CONVERT function and give it a "style" code. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237895(v=sql.80).aspx

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, INTERVAL * 1000, 0), 114)
```

The style code `114` means `hh:mi:ss:mmm` in 24 hr format, with the century on the year if the interval is longer than a century. If you don't require the century digits just use `14` as the style code.

Comment: I would need something like dd:hh:mm and preferably a way to format it with letters in between, ie: `1d 13h 12m`

Comment: Maybe try one of the other style codes in the MSDN link provided. I think you'll need to do some more manipulation to the string, or have a look at the DATEPART function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(v=sql.80).aspx.